# Infinite scroll for mobile phone using Javascript and Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, infinite-scroll

I want to implement infinite scroll for the mobile website.
I want to find a plugin for this which uses JS,PHP and Ajax.

Also it should have show more for scroll like the one in Google Images Search.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 3):

you can find one [here](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/)
PS: jQuery runs fine with smartphones so i guess this should work fine for you.

### Edit

Works perfect in a Windows Phone 7.5

Comment: I don't want to use any JS library!

Comment: you said 'I want to find a plugin for this which uses JS,PHP and Ajax.' And you expect the plugin to be what exactly??

Comment: Plugin should use JavaScript.I don't want to use any JS library for my website.JQuery is a heavy library.

Comment: What I know is that Jquery is Javascript. And I dont understand how is jQuery 'heavy' library. The whole world is using it.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript Library. And by heavy i mean the size of jQuery library is too much to use for mobile websites.

Comment: @hk99 you can probably just swap out jQuery for the smaller Zepto.js

Answer (score 1):

Got a code :

```
<html>
   <body>
   <div id="test">scroll to understand</div>
   <div id="wrapper" style="height: 400px; overflow: auto;">
   <div id="content"> </div>
   </div>
   <script language="JavaScript">
   var more = '<div style="height: 1000px; background: #EEE;"></div>';
   var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
   var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var test = document.getElementById("test");
  content.innerHTML = more;

  function addEvent(obj,ev,fn) {
if(obj.addEventListener) obj.addEventListener(ev,fn,false);
else if(obj.attachEvent) obj.attachEvent("on"+ev,fn);    
 }

 function scroller() {
test.innerHTML = wrapper.scrollTop+"+"+wrapper.offsetHeight+"+100>"+content.offsetHeight;
if(wrapper.scrollTop+wrapper.offsetHeight+100>content.offsetHeight) content.innerHTML+= more;
}

addEvent(wrapper,"scroll",scroller);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But instead of this i want scroll to happen at the end of page as this `jquery` condition this..How to do this in `javaScript`?

`$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()`

Comment: Here is JavaScript example can solve your issues related to javascript http://www.sgeek.org/how-to-implement-infinite-scroll-using-jquery-ajax-php/ .